# Automatic documentation comments creation in Vim

Tags: vim, comments, auto-generate

Is there to make Vim create a comment blurb based on the filetype when I open a new file?

I am new to Vim. Here is the functionality I am looking for. When I do:

```
$ vim hello.py
```

I want the file to start with:

```
#Date Created: 24 May 2012
#Last Modified: (This is optional, really)
#Summary: (enter short summary of program here) 
#Author: My Name
#License: ...
```

etc. I have searched around but I cannot find a solution to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this without skeleton files using the following:

```
 autocmd BufNewFile *.py exe "normal O#Date Created: " . strftime("%d %b %Y") . "\r#Last Modified:\r#Summary:\r#Author:\r#License:\r"
 autocmd BufWritePre *.py exe "%s/^#Last Modified:.*$/#Last Modified: " . strftime("%d %b %Y (%T)") . "/e"
```

Put those in your *vimrc*.

A potential problem is that the `autocmd BufWritePre` will append the current time to **all** lines beginning with:

```
#Last Modified:
```

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the vim autocmd help .. in particular you want [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#skeleton)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based upon pb2q's, but makes it more extensible. Define a function to do the creation, so you can use it for a variety of comment types:

```
function UpdateModifiedTime(comment)
    let savedPosition = getpos(".")
    call cursor(1, 1)
    let modified = a:comment . 'Modified:'
    if search(modified, 'e') > 0
        execute 'substitute/' . modified . '.*/' . modified . ' ' . strftime('%b %d, %Y %T') . '/'
    endif
    call setpos(".", savedPosition)
endfunction
```

(Note: it is my practice to use the longer forms whenever possible in scripting Vim, unless I am [golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=vimscript), because I value code readability and normal commands are arcane).

You can then define autocommands such as:

```
autocmd BufWrite *.sh,*.ksh,*.bash       call UpdateModifiedTime('## ')
autocmd BufWrite *.vim                   call UpdateModifiedTime('" ')
autocmd BufWrite *.py                    call UpdateModifiedTime('')
autocmd BufWrite *.c                     call UpdateModifiedTime('// ')
```

Note that I gave an empty comment character for Python. That's because I had `'''` strings in my file header for the commenting. You can use `'# '` or `'## '` or whatever tickles your fancy.

You can do something similar with `Created`.